# How to full fill a page with a dot generated graph?

Tags: graphics

I have this .dot file with this content:

```
digraph world { size="7,7";
    {rank=same; S8 S24 S1 S35 S30;}
    {rank=same; T8 T24 T1 T35 T30;}
    {rank=same; 43 37 36 10 2;}
    {rank=same; 25 9 38 40 13 17 12 18;}
    {rank=same; 26 42 11 3 33 19 39 14 16;}
    {rank=same; 4 31 34 21 41 28 20;}
    {rank=same; 27 5 22 32 29 15;}
    {rank=same; 6 23;}
    {rank=same; 7;}

    S8 -> 9;
    S24 -> 25;
    S24 -> 27;
    S1 -> 2;
    S1 -> 10;
    S35 -> 43;
    S35 -> 36;
    S30 -> 31;
    S30 -> 33;
    9 -> 42;
    9 -> T1;
    25 -> T1;
    25 -> 26;
    27 -> T24;
    2 -> {3 ; 16 ; 17 ; T1 ; 18}
    10 -> { 11 ; 14 ; T1 ; 13; 12;}
    31 -> T1;
    31 -> 32;
    33 -> T30;
    33 -> 34;
    42 -> 4;
    26 -> 4;
    3 -> 4;
    16 -> 15;
    17 -> 19;
    18 -> 29;
    11 -> 4;
    14 -> 15;
    37 -> {39 ; 41 ; 38 ; 40;}
    13 -> 19;
    12 -> 29;
    43 -> 38;
    43 -> 40;
    36 -> 19;
    32 -> 23;
    34 -> 29;
    39 -> 15;
    41 -> 29;
    38 -> 4;
    40 -> 19;
    4 -> 5;
    19 -> {21 ; 20 ; 28;}
    5 -> {6 ; T35 ; 23;}
    21 -> 22;
    20 -> 15;
    28 -> 29;
    6 -> 7;
    15 -> T1;
    22 -> T35;
    22 -> 23;
    29 -> T30;
    7 -> T8;
    23 -> T24;
    23 -> T1; }
```

How can I render it and fullfill a page?

Comment: What do you mean with `fullfill`?

Comment: What is the purpose of this file? How it was created?

Comment: @azetina I mean fit the full page.

Comment: @Sigur you can generate a png from that .txt file: dot -Tpng chunks.txt -o chunks.png

Comment: I've never heard about dot.

Comment: Check out `dot2texi` package.

Answer (score 1):

I would use this approach. I've installed [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/), modified the system PATH (Windows) and I created a standalone PDF file using `dot` which is cropped afterwards. We could use [`dot2tex`](http://code.google.com/p/dot2tex/) tool and the [`dot2texi`](http://ctan.org/pkg/dot2texi) package. The advantage is you are getting TikZ code out of the dot file, the disadvantage is you need Python and EasyInstall to get it work. It isn't easy to setup it under Windows, I would recommend to try [`dottex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/dottex) and [`graphviz`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphviz) packages for a start.

We are getting automatically or manually the `mal-dots-dot2tex-fig1.dot` file. We process the file this way and the result is a standalone PDF file.

> dot -Tpdf -O mal-dots-dot2tex-fig1.dot
>   pdfcrop --hires --margins 0 mal-dots-dot2tex-fig1.dot.pdf

Next task is to include the PDF file and fit it onto the page. I measure and compare `\paperwidth` and `\paperheight` as well as the width and height of the picture. With these four dimensions in hand we can properly scale wider/higher image in both paper regimes (portrait, landscape). For these tests we use the [`mwe`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mwe) package.

The last task is to place the picture in the middle of the page. I use absolute positioning from the [`TikZ`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) package. It requires two runs of TeX. I am using `lualatex` but `xelatex` and `pdflatex` engines can be used too. For plain `latex` we would need to get `eps` file.

> lualatex mal-dots.tex
>   lualatex mal-dots.tex

You may like to try the [`background`](http://ctan.org/pkg/background) or [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) packages if you want to place picture on more pages. I guess this is not the case. I enclose dot and TeX files and a preview of the typesetted page.

The `mal-dots-dot2tex-fig1.dot` file:

```
// I am the mal-dots-dot2tex-fig1.dot file...
digraph world { size="7,7";
    {rank=same; S8 S24 S1 S35 S30;}
    {rank=same; T8 T24 T1 T35 T30;}
    {rank=same; 43 37 36 10 2;}
    {rank=same; 25 9 38 40 13 17 12 18;}
    {rank=same; 26 42 11 3 33 19 39 14 16;}
    {rank=same; 4 31 34 21 41 28 20;}
    {rank=same; 27 5 22 32 29 15;}
    {rank=same; 6 23;}
    {rank=same; 7;}
    S8 -> 9;
    S24 -> 25;
    S24 -> 27;
    S1 -> 2;
    S1 -> 10;
    S35 -> 43;
    S35 -> 36;
    S30 -> 31;
    S30 -> 33;
    9 -> 42;
    9 -> T1;
    25 -> T1;
    25 -> 26;
    27 -> T24;
    2 -> {3 ; 16 ; 17 ; T1 ; 18}
    10 -> { 11 ; 14 ; T1 ; 13; 12;}
    31 -> T1;
    31 -> 32;
    33 -> T30;
    33 -> 34;
    42 -> 4;
    26 -> 4;
    3 -> 4;
    16 -> 15;
    17 -> 19;
    18 -> 29;
    11 -> 4;
    14 -> 15;
    37 -> {39 ; 41 ; 38 ; 40;}
    13 -> 19;
    12 -> 29;
    43 -> 38;
    43 -> 40;
    36 -> 19;
    32 -> 23;
    34 -> 29;
    39 -> 15;
    41 -> 29;
    38 -> 4;
    40 -> 19;
    4 -> 5;
    19 -> {21 ; 20 ; 28;}
    5 -> {6 ; T35 ; 23;}
    21 -> 22;
    20 -> 15;
    28 -> 29;
    6 -> 7;
    15 -> T1;
    22 -> T35;
    22 -> 23;
    29 -> T30;
    7 -> T8;
    23 -> T24;
    23 -> T1; }
```

The `mal-dots.tex` file:

```
%! *latex mal-dots.tex
%   (twice)
% Needed tool: http://www.graphviz.org/
% Recommended tools: http://code.google.com/p/dot2tex/ and dot2texi package
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % landscape
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[multidot]{grffile}
% \usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
\def\malname{mal-dots-dot2tex-fig1.dot-crop.pdf}
  % example-image-16x9
  % example-image-9x16
\newbox\malbox
\setbox\malbox=\hbox{\includegraphics{\malname}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [remember picture, overlay]
\node at (current page) {%
\ifnum\paperwidth<\paperheight % portrait: page
\ifnum\wd\malbox<\ht\malbox % portrait: picture
  \includegraphics[height=\paperheight]{\malname}%
    \else % landscape: picture
  \includegraphics[angle=90,height=\paperheight]{\malname}%
  \fi % end of \ifnum picture
\else % landscape: page
\ifnum\wd\malbox<\ht\malbox % portrait: picture
  \includegraphics[angle=90,width=\paperwidth]{\malname}%
    \else % landscape: picture
  \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{\malname}%
  \fi % end of \ifnum picture
\fi % end of \ifnum paper
};%
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]